# The origin of $Z_2$ in topological insulators

Tags: topology, topological-insulators

In condensed matter physics, a study of topological insulators use the term $Z_2$ (defined as topology index) very frequently.  What is the origin of $Z_2$? Why not $Z_3$ or $Z$?  My understanding is that it comes from branch of mathematics calls topology and $Z_2$ means it is a group of two possible numbers +1 or -1.  For $Z_3$ means 2,1 or -1 and $Z$ means 1.  Am I correct?

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ means all integers. $\mathbb Z_1$ means $1$.

Comment: No, $\mathbb{Z}$ means all integers (and the for example the integer quantum Hall effect corresponds to topological phases classified by a topological index taking values in the integers $\mathbb{Z}$). $\mathbb{Z}_2$ means the topological index can take two values (and the Hall transport can change by two quanta without closing the gap). The explanation non-interacting fermions and the generic symmetries $T$, $C$, and $S$ only $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ classifications occur needs some amount of algebraic topology and is probably beyond the scope of an answer on this site.

Comment: I also notice that $\mathbb{Z}$ is proportional to $\pi_0$ times $C_0$.  I know that $C$ is the chern number.  What is $\pi$ in physical and mathematical sense?